# Removing quotes when writing list items to CSV

Tags: python

What I am trying to do is remove the quotes while writing the data to a new CSV file.

I have tried using s.splits, and .replaces with no luck. Can you guys point me in the right direction?

**Current Code:**

```
def createParam():
    with open('testcsv.csv', 'r') as f:
        reader = csv.reader(f)
        csvList = list(reader)

    for item in csvList:
        os.mkdir(r"C:\Users\jefhill\Desktop\Test Path\\" + item[0])
        with open(r"C:\Users\jefhill\Desktop\Test Path\\" + item[0] + r"\prm.263", "w+") as f:
            csv.writer(f).writerow(item[1:])
        f.close
```

**Data within testcsv.csv:**

```
0116,"139,data1"
0123,"139,data2"
0130,"35,data678"
```

**Data output when script is ran (in each individual file):**

```
"139,data1"
"139,data2"
"35,data678"
```

**Data I would like:**

```
139,data1
139,data2
35,data678
```

Answer (score 0):

**You can use `str.replace` to replace the " (double quotes) with '' (null).
Then `split` and print all but first item in the list.**

```
with open('outputfile.csv', w) as outfile:       # open the result file to be written
    with open('testcsv.csv', 'r') as infile:     # open the input file
        for line in infile:                      # iterate through each line in input file
            newline = line.replace('"', '')      # replace double quotes with no space
            outfile.write(newline.split(',',maxsplit=1)[1])  # write second element to output file after splitting the newline once
```

You don't need `f.close()` when you use `with open...`